# SQL Server : user cannot connect to my database

Tags: sql-server

I created a user in SQL Server Management Studio, I select `SQL Server authentication` then set `Login name` and `Password` when select master as `Default database`. I can login from another computer but when I select my database this error happen:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to DESIGN-PC.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
> Login failed for user 'User'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Would someone please help me?

Comment: At the **server level**, you create a **login** (not a "user") - but then you also need to create a **user** for each database where this account should have access to - a user based on this login. Did you do that, too?

Answer (score 1):

Change the default database for the user to an existing database. You can do that in Connection properties.

Once you've logged in, set:

```
ALTER LOGIN [theUsernameGoesHere] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = nameOfYourDatabase
```

Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/f1-help/connect-to-server-connection-properties-page-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15